# Apache ant does not recognize 'for' task/macro, although I have added ant-contrib via taskdef

Tags: ant, build

I am getting following while doing ant build:

```
Build\build.xml:247: Problem: failed to create task or type
for
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

build.xml line 247 is `<for param="file">`

Already defined `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>`, it didn't work. Then I specifically added following but it is still not working.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

I have **ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar** at **C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib** directory. 
What is missing here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you placed the AntContrib jar in `$ANT_HOME`/lib directory, all you really need to do is this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

Actually to use the `<for/>` task, you need to do this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
```

Note you have to use `antlib.xml` and not `antcontrib.properties`. Read the [Installation directions](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html) very carefully. It's easy to miss.

If you are doing this in a group project, I recommend that you put your ant-contrib.jar in your project. THen add them to your project in your version control system. That way, other developers can use your build with the ant-contrib tasks without downloading the ant-contrib jar and installing it in their $ANT_HOME directory themselves.

Let's say you create a directory called `ant-contrib.dir` and put that in the root of your project, then put the ant-contrib jar in that folder. Just put this in your project:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
          <fileset dir="${basedir}/ant-contrib.dir"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: Also you could just add ant-contrib as a Maven dependency with <dependency>
      <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
      <version>20020829</version>
     </dependency> and others will get the jar when they run maven.

Comment: The whole purpose of putting the ant-contrib jar into the project is to make it simple to build. Imagine I defined a standard development environment: You need the VCS, Java, and Ant. Someone checking out this project doesn't have to do anything to get it to work even though it requires ant-contrib. It's self contained. I checkout and build. With Maven, I now have to install Maven, then run Maven before I can run Ant.

Answer (score 2):

Ant needs to be aware of the the dependency. The following is a more succinct version of David W's answer. Add the equivalent of the following to your ant project:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="relative/path/to/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="relative/path/to/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
```