# ant-contrib for loop task fails

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

To search for multiple string in a fileset I try to use the ant-contrib for .. loop without success.
The [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) has the following simple example

```
<project name="testing" default="main" basedir=".">

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>

<task name=main">
<echo message="The first five letters of the alphabet are:"/>
  <for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter">
    <sequential>
      <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</task>

</project>
```

That fails with

```
xTest.xml:12: Problem: failed to create task or type for
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

What's wrong with this?

Not sure if I need the taskdef for ant-contrib-0.3.jar

*Note:  ANT is running within Eclipse and it has version: "Apache ANT  1.8.2v20110505-1300"*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant: Not recognizing FOR task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407637/ant-not-recognizing-for-task)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [`taskdef`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) for `ant-contrib-0.3.jar`. The ant-contrib [installation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html) page tells you how to do so:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-version.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Doing this, I have the following definitions in `build.xml`:

```
<project name="sample" basedir=".">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="C:\\Users\\userdomains\\Downloads\\ant-contrib\\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <echo message="The first five letters of the alphabet are:"/>
  <for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter">
    <sequential>
      <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</project>
```

which should now give:

```
Buildfile: c:\build.xml
     [echo] The first five letters of the alphabet are:
     [echo] Letter a
     [echo] Letter b
     [echo] Letter c
     [echo] Letter d
     [echo] Letter e

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Ended up with ant-contrib-0.6.jar to get it running .. NOT -0.3.jar!

Comment: Note that `net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties` is said to work only for ant versions 1.5 or lower on [this](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html) page. If it works for you, great!

Comment: You should use the latest release 1.0b3 / 2006-11-02 and <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"> as S.R.I already stated in his answer and his comment above.

Answer (score -1):

Also the basic example works, the need as described with first posting

> To search for multiple strings in a fileset

isn't solved. Here is what I have right now:

```
<loadfile property="dtdNAMES"  srcFile="_dtdNAMES_1.txt"/>
<echo>.:${dtdNAMES}:.</echo>

<target name="main">
  <for list="xyz.name,xyz.version,xyz.general,xyz.generalXXX,xyz.ok" param="search4" delimiter=",">
  <!--for list="${dtdNames}" param="search4" delimiter=","-->

      <!-- do the stuff here with param -->
      <sequential>

        <fileset id="existing" dir="../src">
            <patternset id="files">
              <include name="content/**/*.xul"/>
            </patternset>
        </fileset>

        <resourcecount property="count">
            <fileset id="matches" dir="../src">
              <patternset refid="files" />
              <contains text="@{search4}" />
            </fileset>
        </resourcecount>

        <echo message="Found '@{search4}' in files : '${count}'"/>
      </sequential>

  </for>
</target>
```

This has **2 problems**:

**ad 1.** the use of <for list=" .. csv  .." just outputs a list with all files and one result like this:

> ```
> [echo] Found 'xyz.name' in files : '3'
> [echo] Found 'xyz.version' in files : '3'
> [echo] Found 'xyz.general' in files : '3'
> [echo] Found 'xyz.generalXXX' in files : '3'
> ```

The result '3' belongs to the very first loop with 'xyz.name', and yes there are 3 matches in all files. But the other strings have other matches in all files. There is no 'xyz.generalXXX' string in any file!

Question: How to get correct results for all strings in all files?

**ad 2.** For flexibility a final solution needs to replace the list string with a property like

> ```
> <for list="${dtdNames}" param="search4" delimiter=",">
> ```

To the property ${dtdNames} is read a string from a srcFile (see above), and yes it's comma separated, no line breaks! And checked with a echo command.

But that reference fails with

> ```
> [echo] Found '${dtdNames}' in files : '0'
> ```

So it seems the <for /> doesn't allow to work with property?
How to write that correctly?

Comment: Just changing from ${dtdNames} to ${list} **solves problem #2**.
` `
But problem #1 still NOT fixed! What would be a solution to get a correct listing for the individual matches of each string in the list in all files?

Comment: You should delete this. It is not an answer.... You have asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753345/ant-contrib-get-count-result-in-resourcecount-nested-in-for-loop/