# ant-contrib: get count result in 'resourcecount' nested in <for/> loop

Tags: xml, ant, ant-contrib

To search for multiple 'searchStrings' in a fileset the following ANT seems to do the job.

```
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <loadfile property="list"  srcFile="searchStrings.txt"/>
  <echo>.:${list}:.</echo>

  <target name="main">
    <for list="${list}" param="search4"  delimiter="${line.separator}">

      <sequential>

        <fileset id="existing" dir="../src">
          <patternset id="files">
            <include name="**/*.xul"/>
          </patternset>
        </fileset>

        <resourcecount property="count">
          <fileset id="matches" dir="../src">
            <patternset refid="files" />
            <contains text="@{search4};" />
          </fileset>
        </resourcecount>

        <echo message="Found '@{search4}' in files : '${count}'"/>
      </sequential>

    </for>
  </target>
```

But for each individual searchString I need the number of occurrences. The echo message "Found ..." only gives the very first result and more worse, it repeats that number for all files.

Tried to add an echo inside the resourcecount block, but that fails.

How can this be modified to get a list for all searchStrings?

Comment: Properties in ANT are immutable, this is why the count value doesn't change.

Comment: I have seen other discussions with a solution using <propertycopy name="tempCount" from="count" override="true" /> .. but also that doesn't work here! Isn't there a possibility to get that "out" so a later task could fetch it for echo message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT is not a scripting language, I would recommend embedding something like [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)

## Example

This example counts the occurances of search terms, stored in the "searchStrings.txt" file, contained files stored under the "src" directory.

```
├── build.xml
├── searchStrings.txt
└── src
    ├── test1.xul
    ├── test2.xul
    └── test3.xul
```

Run as follows

```
$ ant

search:
   [groovy] Found hello in files : 3
   [groovy] Found world in files : 2
   [groovy] Found test in files : 1
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="search">

   <target name="bootstrap" description="Used to install the ivy task jar">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.9/groovy-all-2.1.9.jar"/>
   </target>

   <target name="search">
      <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

      <fileset id="existing" dir="src" includes="**/*.xul"/>

      <groovy>
         new File("searchStrings.txt").eachLine { term ->
            def files = project.references.existing.findAll{
               new File(it.toString()).text.contains(term)
            } 
            println "Found ${term} in files : ${files.size}"
         }
      </groovy>
   </target>

</project>
```

### searchStrings.txt

```
hello
world
test
```

### src/test*.xul

Dummy data files:

```
$ cat src/test1.xul
hello world test

$ cat src/test2.xul
hello world

$ cat src/test3.xul
hello
```

## Update 1

To make this work with Eclipse, alter the taskdef to include the path to the downloaded "groovy-all.jar".

```
  <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy">
     <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
     </classpath>
  </taskdef>
```

Note:

- This solution does not need "ant-contrib". With embedded groovy you'll have more flexibility.

## Update 2:

The solution can be easily enhanced to write the search results to a file:

```
<groovy>
  new File("searchResults.txt").withWriter { writer ->
    new File("searchStrings.txt").eachLine { term ->
      def files = project.references.existing.findAll{
        new File(it.toString()).text.contains(term)
      }
      writer.println "Found ${term} in files : ${files.size}"
    }
  }
</groovy>
```

Groovy is powerful.

Comment: Sounds good .. but getting a build error
`BUILD FAILED
build.xml:18: taskdef class org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]` The line #18 has: '<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>'. The jar is installed in the named dir.

Comment: @gNeandr Run "ant bootstrap". It will download the groovy-all.jar for you.

Comment: Sorry still have problem. Also I'm running the build.xml from within Eclipse with ANT I run "ant bootstrap"; that needed to install ANT. Also done but the error is there. As you see with the op I also added "ant-contrib.jar", is there another method to add the requirements for 'groovy'?

Comment: @gNeandr Try running ANT from the command-line, then it will work. To get it working with Eclipse (which has its own bundled copy of ANT) you'll need to download the groovy-all.jar and add it into the project's classpath. I'll update my script with an alternative mechanism.

Comment: Would be great to get an alternative way. It's intended to use that 'build.xml' as part of an Eclipse project. So it would be best to have it installed in there and used that way. Hope it can be done. Thanks so far ;)

Comment: @gNeandr I updated my answer. Including the groovy-all is the same as including the ant-contrib jar. Consider it a replacement. I have updated my answer. This is a 3rd party jar maintenance issue. You could also drop the jar into the "lib" directory of your ANT distro.

Comment: OK, that mod runs .. at least it runs with all strings stored in 'searchString.txt' but the result for each string is like ` [groovy] Found xx.name in files : 0 `  ... all 0 which isn't the case.

Comment: @gNeandr You gave no indication of what format your searchStrings file had. Please look at my working example and adapt my sample code to match.

Comment: Not clear, but 'searchString.txt' has plain UTF-8 strings, each one on a line, terminated by LF. The files to look into are UTF-8 text files (actually Mozilla XUL files). The idea is to see if a certain text string (a reference to .dtd file exists) in the/any one XUL file exists. So is the build.xml working with that formatting?

Comment: @gNeandr So you're trying to search the content of each file? No, that is not what my example is doing..... AND neither is your example!.... The "resourcecount" task is attempting to count the number of matching filenames, which is what my code sample is doing.

Comment: Ah, both weren't clear to me, sorry! So I need to modify the xml that way it reads each file content into a property and search for the string .. I guess ;(

Comment: @gNeandr I have revised my example to search files for the search terms. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also it's running .. a last wish: How to replace/modify the 'println' so the output is written directly to a new file? _(Couldn't find any description for that in groovy docs)_

Comment: @gNeandr Answer updated with how to adapt solution to write a search result file.